# Get GPS location when application is started in Emulator

Tags: android, gps, emulation

I am testing my application in Android Emulator and I am only able to set a GPS position when the application is already running through the `onLocationChanged` method. I can't set it before I start the application. This is the code in my `onCreate` method:

Edit: Think you guys missunderstood me. I am able to set a GPS position with geo fix when application is running. When I try to set it before I launch the activity I get Error android.view.windowmanager$badtokenexception.

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

Criteria crit = new Criteria();
providers = lm.getBestProvider(crit, false);
loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(providers);
    if (loc != null) {
    title.setText(stop_name);
    lview.setAdapter(lviewAdapter);
      } else {
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to get GPS location", 5000);
        t.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
        t.show();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to set the gps location in emulator you have to follow below steps and open your app before setting up below steps ,then this will go to last configuration .

1. Open command prompt
2. Type "telnet localhost 5554"
3. then type geo fix

[image]

Comment: That works when the application is running. Is it possible to set a position before I launch it?

Comment: could you please run above commands before launching app,it will sure works

Comment: It's not working when I start the application. The code in onProviderDisabled method is shown then.

Comment: you have to use    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As you can see in the image you can send lat/long manually from your eclipse by going to DDMS an add lat/long values manually and send it you can get these points in your emulator by doing this

Comment: This is kind of pictorial representation of my answer.... In an addition to this answer my answer can help you open required windows in any perspective, even if it's other than DDMS...

Answer (score 1):

You even don't need to open command line tool, if you are using eclipse [I hope you do], if not you don't have to reed the rest....

1. Go to window-> Show view-> Other
2. In a dialog box you can find android group[folder]
3. Click on emulator control
4. Adjust the window as per your convenience
5. If you have more than one simulators/devices connected repeat 1 and 2
6. Here you have to click devices
7. In the devices click on desired simulator
8. Again go to emulator control window just opened
9. Find Location Controls [**Keep in mind if selected device is not emulator all the controls in emulator controls are disabled**]
10. Type desired location as per your convenient format.
11. Press send
    And Viola.... you can easily work with locations in emulator